# Create an arrow line between two vertical Annotations

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have a chart with multiple chart areas. There is also a vertical annotation that shows the values of the plotted signal. The user has the option to add a second vertical annotation as well.
What I want to do is create a line between the two vertical annotations like the photo :

[image]

I have tried creating a lineAnnotation with endcap and Start cap as arrows, but I have a difficulty to dock the line annotation on the Vertical annotation.
I have also tried SetAnchor command but it drwas an annotation only between datapoints, and I want to draw it between the X values of the vertical annotation for every chart area.

Comment: _I have tried creating a lineAnnotation with endcap and Start cap as arrows_ Sounds like the right approach. How are the VLAs docked? Are they movable? It often works to code a `AnnotationMoved` event to adapt some things..

Comment: I have used the AnnotationPositionChanging event. My problem is that I don't have a way to set the start and the end value of the line.

Comment: You can only set the x and y positions and the width and height.  x is equal to the 1st vertical one and y is a fixed number you choose. width is v2.x - v1.x, height is 0,

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have tried it, and there seems to be an error regarding the width. For some reason it is mirroring around V2.X value. Do you think that since width gets a value in Pixels that this might be the problem?

Comment: Um, the width and height of an annotation are in the same unit as x and y and never in pixels. (LineWidth is, though..) - Which unit is used depends on the anchoring.